# wrap long sentence with different style in sentences form

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface

I want to show a long sentence in my form.
some words should be in black and some are in blue.
for this I've added different textBlocks and set the Foreground property for each one and put them in Horizontal StackPanel.
But i want it can be wrapped, and by setting WrapText propery of TextBlock it hasn't any effect because it's in StackPanel.
what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) for the the TextBlock

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="This is black text" Foreground="Black"/>
    <Run Text=" While this is blue text!" Foreground="Blue"/>
</TextBlock>
```